# JDB execute a method on "this"

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

Is there a way for JDB to execute an instance method of the class where I stopped with a breakpoint?

I would like to do something like:

```
main[1] this.myMethod()
```

I know that there is the "eval" command and that you can do something like

```
main[1] print new java.lang.Runtime().exec("ls")
```

I have no idea though how I can reference to the "this" pointer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was actually as easy as:

```
eval this.myMethod()
```

Did not load correctly in the first try so it didn't work right away.